# Delete channel in Slack API

Tags: slack-api

I am finishing development of API similar to Slack API, but with more/different features. I have to implement an API (more like command/endpoint) for deleting a room and I can't find anything like that in the documentation.

It seems that it can be done via webUI according to [this help article](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/213185307-Delete-a-channel#delete-a-public-channel).

But there is no method for it in [Slack API methods](https://api.slack.com/methods).

I think there is only [`channels.archive`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.archive) with similar purpose, but it seems very strange not having a method to delete a room.

Is it really like that that room can't be deleted via Slack API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no method for deleting a channel in the official API, but there is the undocumented method [`channels.delete`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/channels.delete.md) that has this exact functionality.

Basic usage is:

```
https://slack.com/api/channels.delete?token=TOKEN&channel=C12345678
```

Please note that undocumented methods are not officially supported by Slack and might change or stop working without any prior warning. Still, they are very useful and I have made a [github](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc) to document all known undocumented methods. Please feel free to use and contribute.

Comment: Great! I started to implement it exactly the same way :)

Comment: Is it possible this is no longer available?  I've been trying to get this to work with a legacy token, but it keeps saying `insufficient_permissions`.  I've been trying to understand if that's not my user token, and if not, how do I get a user token.

Slack does tell me that it includes the 'client' scope, which is what you documented as being necessary...

Comment: no it still works. Just tested it. And it works with a legacy token. Could be that your user does not have the correct role? Try using it with an admin or owner.

Comment: I just used @ErikKalkoken's `slack.py` technique and it works flawlessly

Comment: It seems that this method does nothing now. I invoked using this method and it returned success but does not delete the channel

Comment: It does. I did not have client scope for my auth token. It works after adding client scope

Comment: I'm a little confused. It's possible to create channels via the api but not delete them? So if you accidentally programmatically create very many channels, then you're just out of luck? or has this changed? I see "conversations.close" now.

Answer (score 1):

Tried it today 2nd June 2022 and it responds with 'unknown_methods', I guess it's outdated now.